# Identifying  senders email id while trying to contact the company through Contact Us form

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am building a `Contact Us` form for our Company's website.My requirement is that when a user sends any inquiry through our `Contact Us` page, it should be sent to our company's email id.Lets say `sales@mycompany.in`.I have been provided `SMTP` details `smtp.mycompany.in`.
I earlier tried sending mail from gmail it was working.
Here is my code.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);
mail.To.Add("sales@mycompany.in");
mail.Subject = "Mail from www.mycompany.in";
mail.Body =  emailbody.ToString();
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //Or Your SMTP Server Address
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
("mycompany@gmail.com", "xxxxxx");
//Or your Smtp Email ID and Password
// smtp.Port=80; 
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

The problem with this code is that when I send mail it is recieved at `sales@mycompany.in` but it always says that the message is from `mycompany@gmail.com` instead of the typed email adress `txtEmail.Text`.I know that is because of the gmail credentials that I provided.So  my queston to you guys how can I get it to work such that I know the email id of the sender or the person contacting us.Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Please search the site for "sending email trough gmail [c#]" [link](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sending+email+trough+gmail+%5Bc%23%5D). This has been asked so many times here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Comment: @Oded I know it has been asked so many times.I just need to sort the problem so that I get to know the email id from the mail has been sent.

Comment: @Oded I am not asking about sending mail through gmail.

Comment: @freebird: Then you should better change your question title with your problem !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in this way, as some one is abc@yahoo.com other is xyz@hotmail.com, and you can't send it to appear from the account of someone else.

My suggestion is to add the email address of sender in the body of email that the guy with this email is contacting us but the solution you are trying to do, i think is not possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I think including the senders address in email might be the way.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

#### In Theory

You can't send a message “on behalf of” somebody else if you're using Gmail SMTP.
It won't allow you to set custom Reply-To address either.

If you roll out your own SMTP server, you should be good though.

#### In Practice

One way to make it less painful both for customers and the support is to set up a ticketing system.
You can code one yourself, if you like, or use any of [plenty of existing ones](http://google.com?search?q=email+support+ticket+system+open+source).

Comment: That means I should include it in my body so that I am aware of the sender.Thanks a lot.

Comment: The smtp standard doesn't prevent you from using any from-address. But I do believe GMail only allows it if that email address has specifically allowed sending on its behalf.

Comment: Yeah. One way to simplify this for end-users would be to use ticketing system.